# Execute link on selection by Firefox Webextension addon

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I would like to write a Firefox Webextension which executes a link on a selected coordinate.

It should convert a coordinate like -34.802551,-58.438485 (x,y) into a link

http://127.0.0.1:8111/load_and_zoom?left=(x-0.1)&right=(x+0.1)&top=(y-0.1)&bottom=(x+0.1)

which is the JOSM remote control.

I've found the following snippet:

```
browser.menus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  browser.search.search({
    query: info.selectionText,
    engine: ??
  });
});
```

How to adapt this?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need this:

```
browser.menus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  let selection = info.selectionText;
  let x = selection.split(",")[0];
  let y = selection.split(",")[1];

  browser.tabs.create({
    url: `http://127.0.0.1:8111/load_and_zoom?left=(${x}-0.1)&right=(${x}+0.1)&top=(${y}-0.1)&bottom=(${x}+0.1)`;
  });
});
```

It will open the new tab with the coordinates you selected.

Comment: And how can I package this web extension to an XPI? I can't get information on how the metadata file is called and what it must contain.

Comment: Read about web-ext build and manifest.json: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Getting_started_with_web-ext and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json